# Are variables declared in <script></script> section on vue component global?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I had problems to use `v-for` directive on a component that has a timer.
The father component uses the issued component like this:

```html
<v-card
  v-for="(gestio, id) in tasca.gestions"
  :key="'tasca-gestio-' + id"
>
  ...
  <gestio-timing :gestio="gestio" />
  ...
</v-card>
```

The issued component has a timer which is updated every second. The variable where I store the interval is defined before the export of the *logic* of the component. Is here where I have the problem. I observed that each component uses and **overrides** the same variable `interval`.

I could see that because when I set another interval on the whole function `setTempsPausada` with random milliseconds as timeout **it worked** (the timer updates every second). And without that last interval, when I declared interval variable on `data` section it worked too.

My question is, how that could happened? Can somebody explain me how it works?

Thanks

Issued component:

```js
<template>
 ...
</template>
<script>
  import moment from 'moment'

  let interval = null   // Timeout variable which I had the issue

  export default {
    name: 'GestioTiming',
    data() {
      return {
        pausaAcumulada: 0, // Amount of seconds
        tempsPausat: ''    // String to show on DOM
      }
    },
    ...,
    watch: {
      'gestio.pauses': {
        handler (value, oldValue) {
          this.setTempsPausada()
        },
        deep: true
      },
    },
    methods: {
      setTempsPausada () {
        this.pausaAcumulada = 0
        clearInterval(interval)

        // stuff

        interval = setInterval(() => {  // Increments amount of seconds each second
          this.pausaAcumulada++
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

## Edit

Sandbox created: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-mcclintock-yxy1c?file=/src/components/GestioTiming.vue)

[image: Edit funny-mcclintock-yxy1c]

Comment: Is it possible to create jsfiddle or similar with your code?

Comment: I'm not sure if I could. I should use `Vue.component(component)` to declare the 2 components I need to reproduce the example and this is not the way I declare my components. I use single .vue file for each component with their own `template` tag where I have the problem.

Comment: codesandbox.io would work for you to create a issue template.

Comment: @VaritJPatel Sandbox done! Thanks

Comment: this.interval is reactive property while interval is not in terms of Vue.